# Solr result filter for user specific data

Tags: solr, filter

I'd like to manipulate the result of a solr server search. I don't think it's possible on the Server side filter, because the information is only available on the client side at runtime.

I tried following:

```
private void filterKernSortiment ( SolrDocumentList docsList )
{
    List<SolrDocument> filteredItems = new ArrayList<SolrDocument>();

    Iterator<SolrDocument> iter = docsList.iterator();
    while ( iter.hasNext() )
    {
        SolrDocument doc = iter.next();

        String artnr = doc.getFieldValue( "artnr" ).toString();
        String lfnt = doc.getFieldValue( "lfnt" ).toString();

        if (  ! user.isForUserInStock( artnr, lfnt ) )
        {
            filteredItems.add( doc );
        }
    }
    log.debug( "filteredItems=" + filteredItems.size() );

    Iterator<SolrDocument> iterFilter = filteredItems.iterator();
    while ( iterFilter.hasNext() )
    {
        SolrDocument doc = iterFilter.next();
        docsList.remove( doc );
    }
}
```

The SolrDocumentList is filtered correctly, but the getFacetField function gives the result of the unfiltered SolrDocumentList.
Do I have to manipulate the FacetField Lists too or do you know a a better solution for the problem?

Comment: Why cant the information be passed from client side to server side before the query is made to Solr. Filtering facets their counts would be problem as you wouldn't know to which documents they belong as well you wouldn't have the complete list of documents as well.

Comment: Every SolryDocument is a item. The user has the possibility to add a mark sign at runtime for some items. If I pass the information (usernumber) to the Server side, I must read the marked items from an database, that will be slow, because the max marked items are in max 300.000 items. On the Client side I have allready these informations.